# Whatever I do my activatedRoute queryParams is always empty

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm not sure what can possible go wrong here. I have a URL wiht a query parameter

```
?search=something
```

In one of my components I try to extract it

```
const input = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.search;
```

This is the public demo url: https://angular-ivy-pjfam6.stackblitz.io/?search=something

The code: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pjfam6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpersist-input-state.directive.ts)

Seems to work, in the log I actually the the queryParam in the route-trace-log, but at the point I try to extract it, its gone. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: it seems that if I not go for the snapsho

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(qp => {
   const input = qp?.search;
   this.element.nativeElement.value = input;
});
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tmdsib?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpersist-input-state.directive.ts)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of accessing the params:

1 - `route.snapshot.paramMap`

2 - `route.paramMap.subscribe`

If you don't want to update your parameter in the same component you are accessing it, you can use `snapshot`.

`snapshot` is sync and when using `snapshot` you get the value once the component loads:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.input = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("search")
}
```

But if you want to update the parameter in the same component, then you have to use a subscription
You should subscribe it to get the value:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params: ParamMap => {
             this.input= +params.get('search');
             console.log(params);     
          });
}
```

When you subscribe each time the value is updated you can get it.

Comment: I just did :) and I can confirm that this works. But why doesn't the snapshot solution work?

Comment: Maybe because snapshot is sync and subscribe is async.

Comment: does that explain why its out of sync in my code?

Comment: I updated my answer for better understanding of snapshot and subscribe.

Comment: Ok, I assume that with `param` you mean `queryParams` because they are different things. And, as you state in your anwser: if you want only the value once use snapshop, right? This last thing is exactly what I'm trying to do. Inside ngOnInit/ngAfterViewInit I want to extract that value one, but is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

ngOnInit() { 
    const input = this.route.snapshot.params.search;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const input:Observable<string>= this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(map(p=> p.search));
```

Try using this